# Theme update deleted my custom page

Tags: themes, child-theme, updates

I have a WordPress install on my own server for testing reasons, as I want to use WordPress in professional situations. I used WP before, but that was long time ago and this is the first time I ran in to this.

I set up a site with Customizr theme. I made one of the pages use a custom theme I created. I managed to do this by copying my theme file in the Customizr theme folder.

When a Customizr update happened it deleted my file. **Is there a way to avoid this to happen or I have to keep it in mind that any custom file will be deleted at every update?**

It is problematic, because I think it is good to have up to date files. On the other hand if at every update I have to set up everything again... it just doesn't worth it. **Is there a way to protect files and settings from theme update?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any custom file in a theme directory will be deleted at every update. Adaptations to a theme should be in a separate directory according tot the rules for [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: Can I use the child theme on a single page while using the main theme on all other part of the site?

Comment: Ok I solved it. Made a simple child theme, copied the custom file there and now it runs on the child theme. I waiting for an update to see how it goes. :) Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Or download an [older version of the theme](https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/customizr/) and test it immediately